# karate how to parse stringified json response

Tags: karate

I got a response like this.

```
"{\"statusCode\":204,\"output\":\"{\\n  \\\"Id\\\" : \\\"884d39b8-4afc-4ee3-807a-9d6dbde8c390\\\",\\n  \\\"temp\\\" : \\\"33\\\",\\n  \\\"lastUpdateAuthor\\\" : null\\n}\"}"
```

How can I parse this response and do something like

```
* def expectedOutput = 
"""
{
      "Id": "884d39b8-4afc-4ee3-807a-9d6dbde8c390",
      "temp": "33",
      "lastUpdateAuthor": null
    }
  Scenario: Testing a PUT endpoint with request body
    Given path 'v0'
    And request input
    When method put
    Then match status 200
    And match JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response).output) == expectedOutput
```

The last line of code got skipped by Karate.

Any input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured that out.

```
* def expectedOutput = 
"""
{
  "Id": "884d39b8-4afc-4ee3-807a-9d6dbde8c390",
  "temp": "33",
  "lastUpdateAuthor": null
}
"""
  Scenario: Testing a PUT endpoint with request body
    Given path 'v0'
    And request input
    When method put
    Then match status 200
    And json convertJSON = $
    And json convertJSON = convertJSON.output
    And match convertJSON.latitude == expectedOutput
```

It worked.

Comment: great ! please do mark your own answer as "accepted" once the system lets you do so. thanks !